# Why tag [a] is not allowed, but all other letters are allowed

Tags: support, tags

I just tried to post a question with a Latin alpabet tags, and have been notified that tag [a](/questions/tagged/a) is not allowed. Why it is not allowed?

> [image: a is not allowed]

Despite of allowing any other single letter tag.

Seems this affects all of SE sites.

Comment: What happens if `a` isn't the *first* tag?

Comment: @Oded it still complains about the `a`. The other letters seem to be fine. Apparently it's a globally blacklisted tag?

Comment: @Oded I tried to add `a` in this post as 3rd tag and it still complains.

Comment: 'a' is maybe a blocked tag, because it was created and burniated several times? A mod or a person with enough reputation should be able to check if that tag is blocked.

Comment: Hypothesis: because it's frequently used as an indefinite article? As in "a thread". Type that into the tags field, you'll get `[a] [thread]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few very common words that are not allowed as tags - `and`, `or`, `the`, `a` and a few others (this is configurable, so the list can change, which is why I am not listing all of them).

I believe this was done so edits would get rejected when a user simply writes a sentence in the tag input instead of actual tags.

Comment: Is this list site specific or global wide even for localized sites?

Comment: It is global, though can be customised per site. I'd expect you would need to  post a feature request on the per-site meta for changes to happen (and they would require a compelling reason).

Comment: I need to create a programming language or technology with the name "a" at least!

Comment: Given the average grammar skills on Stack Exchange, [i] needs to be blacklisted as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel i would love to see the research on how English is used in the site

Comment: I could also see it being done to prevent an ambiguous [a] tag when asking a question about the HTML <a> tag.