# Using multiple forbidden tags says about one single tag

Tags: bug, tags, plurals, blocked-tags

When I try to use multiple [forbidden tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298299/339911), the message box text is the concatenated text of all the tags, as if it is one tag.

> [image: one tags]

In this case the correct form could be the next:

> The 'a', 'the', 'or', 'on' tags are not allowed.

Comment: Downvoters, do you really think that [multiple tags should be showed as single](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS6PU.png)?

Comment: This is something users will only ever see if they did something very, very wrong in the tags box. I imagine the downvotes are because "who cares." I don't think it's worth the effort making the code slightly more complicated to account for such a rare case.

Comment: @animuson God is in the detail.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment and what God has to do with this

Comment: @AnthonyPham this is the idiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail

Comment: Then use the actual idiom.

Comment: @Catija Both idioms are presented within the same Wikipedia article

Comment: It is very easy (slow networks, javascript gilitches) for users to generate strings that might pass the first test (during character entry), but then not the final one (that makes the warning we see here.) They might feel bad: "Why didn't you warn me when I was typing?" Well at least the final error message should be properly formatted.

Answer (score 8):

This is really something that's turning an anthill into a mountain.

One, if you are getting that message, you are doing something really, really wrong in the first place and probably need a visit to the Help Center on using tags. I mean why do you use four random words as tags if you need your tags to be specific about your problem? This is a really small problem that usually represents that the OP has a relatively medium sized problem with using tags appropriately and honestly, who cares about a case that probably appears one in a few-hundred-thousand/million times?

The message gets its meaning straight either way: don't use them! As @animuson said:

> This is something users will only ever see if they did something very, very wrong in the tags box. I imagine the downvotes are because "who cares." I don't think it's worth the effort making the code slightly more complicated to account for such a rare case.

---

**But...** there could be a small, minor change to quickly change this. Instead of:

> The 'list of tag(s)' is not allowed.

We can change it to:

> The following tag(s) are not allowed: 'list of tag(s)'

Comment: On a cellphones' keyboard / cramped screen etc. It is very easy to generate tags that one thinks were already in the system, only to find out they finally were not, thus provoking the warning.