# Forbidden tags popup isn’t consistent

Tags: bug, tags, design, blocked-tags

My previous related [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298302/339911) has been drastically downvoted. But now I see that at least on Stack Overflow some forbidden tags are shown in a single line (old BR), others one per separate line.

> [image]

Looks like the global forbidden tags like “a, on, the” are processed different from site-specific tags like “data” and “programming”.

I think there should be a consistent solution. I suggest that each tag on separate line could be a better choice. E.g.:

> - The 'data' tag is not allowed.
> - The 'programming' tag is not allowed.
> - The 'a' tag is not allowed.
> - The 'the' tag is not allowed.
> - The 'on' tag is not allowed.

Suggested duplicate post is not a duplicate of the current one. The old post displays **all** forbidden tags in a single line. Current - contains new **site-specific** forbidden tags, which are displayed one per line. Both issues are very similar, but they are about different situations.

Comment: How is this different from your previous bug report?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The old one based on the situation that all forbidden tags listed in one line. Now you can see, that it was incorrect: some tags are listed in the separate lines. Old one is about adding “s” when multiple tags are used, the current one is about make consistent solution for all forbidden tags. I.e. they could be the same if you would see “a the on data programming” in single line. But this’s not.

Comment: Too bad we can't close as duplicate based on comment, because the comment on your previous report holds 100% true here as well, word by word: "This is something users will only ever see if they did something very, very wrong in the tags box. I imagine the downvotes are because "who cares." I don't think it's worth the effort making the code slightly more complicated to account for such a rare case". [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] There are times when it's better not to submit a bug report, when you know for utter certainty it's too minor to fix. The first time you reported is still fine, I didn't downvote for example, but now that you know from official SE employee it's too minor to fix, I think it's not OK to submit very similar report, with exactly the same "impact", so I have downvoted based on that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are welcome with your downvote :) But there is a difference between minor to fix (a) when you need to write new functionality (add plurality for old question), and (b) when you need to use another branch of already fixed code with removing the wrong code with different behavior for the same things (i.e. forbidden tags). Again and again I’m disappointing with the policy when minor bugs are downvoting. Tons of unfixed and known minor bugs don’t show the quality of the product.

Comment: If the bug happens during valid and reasonable use of the site, I agree it should be reported and fixed even when minor. But the main point in those two reports is not the bug being minor actually, but rather that it happens while doing something that ordinary user will never do.

Comment: @ShadowWizard completely disagree. There would not forbidden tags at all if ordinary users didn’t try to use them.

Comment: An ordinary user might try to use one blocked tag at a time, sure, but it's unlikely someone would normally end up using a bunch of different blocked tags at once unless they're trying to see how the system handles that. (Depending on the site and which tags are blocked there, of course, but most sites don't have too many blocked tags that people are likely to use at the same time.)