# Open links in browser via long tap menu

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, ios-app

Some links from posts can be opened in app, another links can be opened in browser only. But sometimes I want to open 1st type link in browser too. [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298293/339911) tag link:

> [image: long tap menu]

Is it possible to add to this menu ability to open link in browser?

Currently "Open" item works as if short tap was performed.